# Finding The Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

let there be $T: \mathbb{R}_{2}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{4}[x]$ a linear transformation

When

$T(1)=x$

$T(1+x)=x^2+x^3$

$T(1+x+x^2)=1-x^2+x^4$

$T(ax^{2}+bx+c)=\alpha_1x^{4}+\alpha_2x^{3}+\alpha_3x^{2}+\alpha_4x+\alpha_5$

Find: $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4,\alpha_5$ by $a,b,c$

points I have noticed:

$(1,1+x,1+x+x^2)$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}_{2}[x]$ can I used this, should I write both sides ( $\mathbb{R}_{2}[x] | \mathbb{R}_{4}[x]$) in a matrix to find the corresponding expression of each element of the basis?

I can turn the expression $T(ax^{2}+bx+c)$ to $aT(x^{2})+bT(x)+cT(1)$

How should I approach this question?

Comment: Hint: $x=(1+x)-x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let denote $\mathcal B_c$ the standard basis of  $\Bbb R_4[x]$ and let the basis $\mathcal B=(1,1+x,1+x+x^2)$ of $\Bbb R_2[x]$. By hypothesis we see that the matrix of $T$ relative to the basis $\mathcal B$ onto the canonical basis is

$$[T]_{\mathcal B_c}^{\mathcal B}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&-1\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
and let $P$ the change matrix from standard basis of $\Bbb R_2[x]$ to the basis $\mathcal B$:

$$P=[\operatorname{id}]_{\mathcal B_c}^{\mathcal B}=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
so finally the matrix of $T$ relative to the standard basis is
$$[T]_{\mathcal B_c}^{\mathcal B_c}=P^{-1}[T]_{\mathcal B_c}^{\mathcal B}P$$